# Передача строк из Memo в массив \ DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

Что не правильно сделано в коде ?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
fall, f1: TextFile;
S: string;
mas : array [0..3000] of string;
i: integer;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
     AssignFile(fall, OpenDialog1.FileName);
     reset(fall);
     AssignFile(f1, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\Resultat_1.txt');
     rewrite(f1);
     end;

 // Вот тут не могу понять правильно сделала или ?????
 for i:=0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
 mas[i] := Memo1.Lines.Strings[i];

//работаем по строкам в файле
 while not Eof(fall) do
  begin
 //читаем строку
  ReadLn(fall, S);

// Поиск строки используя строки из memo  - mas[i]
if (Pos(mas[i], s) > 0)
then
writeln(f1, S);
   end;

CloseFile(fall);
CloseFile(f1);
end;
```

Comment: Татьяна, `Memo1.Lines` содержит строки или нет? Из кода это непонятно. Еще одно. У Вас массив - статический. Вы уверены что размера в 3000 ед. будет достаточно? А если `Memo1` будет содержать *больше* строк?

Comment: @Dima, Да, в memo1 я ввожу слова, по которым, из текстового файла - программа ищет строки. Ну а массив можно сделать динамический вот так array of string; Или как правильно будет ?.

Comment: Да, массив я бы сделал динамическим и выставлял бы его размер эквивалентным количеству строк в `Memo1`. И еще одно: что *конкретно* не работает?

Comment: @Dima, ну ввожу в memo1 слова для поиска строк - в текстовом файле. И программа просто создает пустой файл. То есть не ищет ничего, где то в коде ошибка...

Comment: Еще одно уточнение: имя файла точно *Reaultat_1*? Может быть `Resultat_1`?

Comment: @Dima, Да, Resultat_1, то я просто опечатку сделала...

Comment: Татьяна, я изменил код в ответе (прочитайте описание изменений) и проверьте, подходит ли он Вам. Я закомментировал "старые" участки кода для возможного дальнейшего использования.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.** Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте применить следующее решение.
Основные изменения по сравнению с Вашим кодом

1. Заменен статический массив на динамический.
2. В цикле добавлена проверка на выход за пределы массива при чтении файла
3. Использование функций `Low` и `High` для получения минимального и максимального допустимых индексов массива.

**Внимание**
*Код был изменен (благодаря участнику **zed**) чтобы искать вхождение каждой строки, находящейся в массиве, в строке, прочитанной из файла.*

Собственно, сам код

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fall, f1: TextFile;
  S: String;
  mas: Array of String;
  Found: Boolean;
  PathToFileToRead: String;
  PathToFileToWrite: String;
  Opened: Boolean;
  i: integer;
begin
  // Инициализируем переменную, чтобы в случае любых проблем с открытием диалога
  // для выбора файлов, у нас не произошо чтение несуществующего файла
  Opened := false;

  // Запускаем диалог выбора файла
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      PathToFileToRead := OpenDialog1.FileName;
      PathToFileToWrite := ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\Resultat_1.txt';
      Opened := true;
    end;

  // Проверяем, был ли успешно открыт файл.
  // Если Opened = false, значит файл не был открыт 
  // (нажали на "Отмена" в диалоге выбора файла).
  if not Opened then
    Exit;

  // Открываем файл для чтения
  AssignFile(fall, PathToFileToRead);
  Reset(fall);

  // Открываем файл для записи
  AssignFile(f1, PathToFileToWrite);
  Rewrite(f1);

  // Установим размер массива равный количеству строк Memo1
  SetLength(mas, Memo1.Lines.Count);
  for i:=Low(mas) to High(mas) do
    mas[i] := Memo1.Lines.Strings[i];

  // Работаем по строкам в файле, открытом для чтения
  while not EoF(fall) do
    begin
      // Читаем строку
      ReadLn(fall, S);

      // Поиск строки используя строки из memo  - mas[i]
      for i:=Low(mas) to High(mas) do
        begin
          Found := (Pos(mas[i], S) > 0);
          if Found then
            WriteLn(f1, S);
        end;
    end;

  // Закроем файлы
  CloseFile(fall);
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
```

*Примечание: свойство WordWrap у компонента Memo1 необходимо выставить в состояние false, в противном случае, текст внутри компонента "переносится" на другую строку с добавлением специальных символов перевода строки (CRLF), что выражается в создании дополнительных строк внутри компонента, и может повлиять на итоговый результат работы кода.*

Дополнительная информация:

- Функции [Low](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Low.html) и [High](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_High.html)
- Немного о массивах [Arrays in Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Static_Arrays)

Comment: Слово, в слово скопировала ваш код. Но почему то также создает пустой файл и строки не ищет ?

Comment: @Татьяна, не может такого быть. Лично протестировал. В файл записывает. Вы точно в `Memo1` добавляете текст? И он отображается построчно? Если в `Memo1` нет текста, то массив не будет сформирован, соответственно, никакой проверки и записи в файл.

Comment: @Татьяна, попробуйте в функции `AssignFile` подставить текущие пути файлов. Возможно, дело в `OpenDialog1` (я тестировал без него).

Comment: Спасибо, разобралась. У меня проблема была в путях к файлу. Теперь все работает как нужно.

Comment: @Татьяна, вот и славно!

Comment: Может я не правильно понял задачу, но по-моему, строку сравнения (`Pos`) надо было обернуть циклом `for` по строчкам из массива. Т.е. оно же должно записывать строку в файл, если в ней присутствует хотя бы одна из подстрок из memo?

Comment: @zed, немного не верно. Во-первых, посмотрите исходный код в вопросе (там сравнение заключено в цикле `while...do`), во-вторых - мы же читаем из файла построчно и сравниваем прочитанную строку со строкой из массива (в котором содержатся строки из `Memo1`). Если делать по Вашему варианту, то придется скопировать строки из `Memo1` в массив А, затем построчно прочитать файл и записать его в массив Б и потом уже циклом `for...do` провести сравнение строк обоих массивов. Немного заковыристо (на мой взгляд). К тому же при ответе я отталкивался от исходного кода, предоставленного автором вопроса.

Comment: Исходный код в вопросе не работал, так что ссылаться на него нет смысла. В массиве `mas` лежат ключевые слова, по которым надо проверять **все** строки из файла. Текущий же вариант проверяет первую строку с первым словом, вторую со вторым, а третью строку он вообще не будет ни с чем проверять, если задано только 2 ключевых слова. По-моему, это совсем не та задача, которую хотела решить @Татьяна.

Comment: @zed, кстати да, хорошая идея. Обмишурился )). Сейчас переделаю и протестирую.

Comment: @zed, теперь поиск действительно стал *объективнее* ) Спасибо!

Comment: @zed, А Вы просто замечательно - подметили. Я только что сама увидела и хотела вопрос задать, думала что это с моей стороны что то не то (уже всю голову сломала). Ребята zed, Dima - спасибо Вам От Чистого сердца, Вы профессионалы своего дела! Низкий поклон Вам!

Comment: @Dima, А еще такой вопрос. Нажимаю на кнопку открыть файл, после чего запускается Opendialog и тут самое интересное: Когда нажимаю на кнопку в Opendialog (открыть и открываю файл, то все работает). А Когда нажимаю на кнопку в Opendialog (отмена, то есть не выбираю файл) то получаю ошибку в виде - Ошибка: Exception class EInOutError with message 'I/O error 104. И выделяется строка в коде - while not EoF(fall) do. Как это можно исправить ?. Я понимаю что ошибка не значительная но все же интересно ?

Comment: @Татьяна, это происходит вследствие того, что в коде отсутствует проверка на то, был ли выбран файл. Я ее добавил - теперь должно все быть в порядке.

Comment: @Dima, Теперь все отлично. А я почему то думала, в меру своей неопытности, что где то end; было неправильно закрыто. Еще раз спасибо, приятного рабочего дня.