# Передача данных из текста в Pos

Tags: delphi

Сейчас беру данные в цикле из memo.

```
If (Pos(memo1.lines[i], s)> 0) 
then
```

Интересует вариант

```
if Pos(.....путь к файлу со строками которые нужно найти, s) > 0)
then
```

И в теории, возможно ли это сделать?

**Собственно вопрос:**
Как добавить цикл, который будет проверять прочитанную из файла строку со строками, которые идут - в качестве фильтрующих. И записать результат - найденные строки в отдельный файл.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888671

Comment: И ещё один: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887254

Comment: @zed, но на мой не похожий. У меня совсем другое направление. У меня передача из файла данных.

Comment: Почитайте внимательно ответы на те вопросы - там всюду идёт работа с файлами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опираясь на текст и код в Вашем вопросе, могу предложить следующий вариант решения задачи.
Он позволит избежать создания промежуточного `TStringList` и обращения к его строкам, что уменьшит расход ресурсов и ускорит работу цикла.

**Ответ обновлен!**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileToRead: TextFile;
  FileToWrite: TextFile;
  FilterFileToRead: TextFile;
  ReadString: String;
  FileNameRead: String;
  FileNameWrite: String;
  FilterFileName: String;
  FilterStringsArr: Array of String;
  Found: Boolean;
  S: String;
  StringAmount: Integer;
  Index: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  FileNameRead := 'Путь к файлу для чтения';
  FileNameWrite := 'Путь к файлу для записи';
  FilterFileName := 'Путь к файлу со строками для фильтра';

  if not FileExists(FileNameRead) or
     not FileExists(FileNameWrite) or
     not FileExists(FilterFileName)
  then
    Exit;

  // Открываем файл для подсчета количества фильтрующих строк
  StringAmount := 0;
  AssignFile(FilterFileToRead, FilterFileName);
  try
    Reset(FilterFileToRead);
    while not EoF(FilterFileToRead) do
      begin
        ReadLn(FilterFileToRead, S);
        Inc(StringAmount);
      end;
  finally
    // Закрываем файл
    CloseFile(FilterFileToRead);
  end;

  // Устанавливаем размер массива фильтрующих строк
  SetLength(FilterStringsArr, StringAmount);

  // Открываем файл для загрузки фильтрующих строк в массив
  Index := 0;
  AssignFile(FilterFileToRead, FilterFileName);
  try
    Reset(FilterFileToRead);
    while not EoF(FilterFileToRead) do
      begin
        ReadLn(FilterFileToRead, S);
        FilterStringsArr[Index] := S;
        Inc(Index);
      end;
  finally
    // Закрываем файл
    CloseFile(FilterFileToRead);
  end;

  // Открываем файл для чтения
  AssignFile(FileToRead, FileNameRead);
  try
    Reset(FileToRead);

    // Открываем файл для записи
    AssignFile(FileToWrite, FileNameWrite);
    try
      Rewrite(FileToWrite);

      // Работаем со строками в файле, открытом для чтения
      while not EoF(FileToRead) do
        begin
          // Читаем строку из файла
          ReadLn(FileToRead, ReadString);

          // Ищем вхождение фильтрующей строки в прочитанной строке
          for i:=Low(FilterStringsArr) to High(FilterStringsArr) do
            begin
              Found := (Pos(FilterStringsArr[i], ReadString) > 0);
              // Записываем строку в файл
              if Found then                
                WriteLn(FileToWrite, ReadString);
            end;
        end;
    finally
      // Закрываем файл
      CloseFile(FileToWrite);
    end;
  finally
    // Закрываем файл
    CloseFile(FileToRead);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Dima, То есть сюда грузить список черезLoadFromFile, то есть S := 'Ваша строка для поиска'; Я тут немного в ступор ушел

Comment: @Денис, т.е. Вам нужно что-то вроде фильтра? Тогда необходимо добавить цикл, который будет проверять прочитанную *из файла* строку со строками, которые Вы предоставите в качестве фильтрующих. Дело в том, что в вопросе нет и намека на множественную проверку. Тогда хоть вопрос расширьте и *поточнее* укажите, что конкретно Вам необходимо. Потому что на Ваш текущий вопрос мой ответ отвечает полностью.

Comment: Да, именно так и нужно. Я исправил вопрос. Сможете помочь доделать данный код ?

Comment: @Денис, фильтрующие строки откуда берутся? Они фиксированы (прописаны в коде) или загружаются из файла?

Comment: Dima, фильтрующие строки берутся (загружаются) из файла (.txt).

Comment: @Денис какое количество фильтрующих строк содержится в файле?

Comment: Dima, в данном случае - каждый раз по разному. То есть 5, 10, 30 а бывает и 70.

Comment: Dima, так а найденные строки - не записываются в новый текстовый файл. В вашем коде я пишу if Found then WriteLn(FileToRead, S); И ничего не происходит. То есть не создается файл с результатами...

Comment: @Денис, переменная `S` - это просто временный буфер для прочитанной строки, который используется при подсчете количетва строк в файле-фильтре. В файл следует записывать строку `ReadString`. Причем файла для записи в примере нет. Про запись речи вообще не было!

Comment: А с записью я точно застыл... :). Нужно что бы была еще запись результатов. Добавил в вопрос, что бы не создавать новую тему.

Comment: Dima, Мега-ресспект Вам. Буду разбираться в структуре кода. Все работает отлично.

Answer (score 1):

Делаем так:

```
var
  L: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  L := TStringList.Create;
  L.LoadFromFile('1.txt');

  // И уже в цикле:
  for I := 0 to L.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if (Pos(L[I], strochka) > 0) then
      WriteLn(faylrez, strochka);
  end;

  L.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Придирка, конечно, но блок `try...finally` не помешал бы ;)

Comment: @Dima, не спорю, Вы правильно сказали. Кстати от этого скорость не поменялась. То есть что с memo чтение было, что с файла. Есть варианты как можно ускорить ? Или это максимум ?

Comment: Денис, это не ускорит выполнение кода, но избавит Вас от проблем с утечкой памяти, если по каким-либо причинам в цикле возникнет `AV` или еще чего.