# Разбитие файла по количеству строк

Tags: delphi

Есть текстовый файл, **в котором 150 строк**. Указываю **число 15 (на сколько строк разбить)** и программа разбивает его на файлы, в каждом из которых 15 строк. Получаю результат в виде **10 файлов по 15 строк в каждом**. Если остается остаток меньше 15 строк то его записываем в последний файл.

Вот начал делать. Подскажите где проколы?

```
    procedure Tfrm_Main.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl, Arr:TStringList;
  i, j:integer;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
  i:=0;
  sl:=TStringList.Create;
  Arr:=TStringList.Create;
  sl.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.filename);

    while i<15 do
    begin
      Arr.Clear;

        for j:=0 to 15 do
        begin
          if i<15 then
          Arr.Add(sl[i]);
          inc(i);
        end;

    end;
    Arr.SaveToFile(Format('part%d', [(i-1) div 15]));
  sl.Free;
  Arr.Free;
end;
end;
```

UP:
Если возможно то чтением построчно - поскольку 1 гигабайт оперативной памяти на ПК.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Опираясь на данные в вопросе, пришел к следующему решению.

**Ответ был изменен!**

### Вариант чтения из загруженного файла

```
procedure TForm1.aButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SourceFile: TStringList;
  OutputFile: TStringList;
  OutputFileName: String;
  FileExt: String;
  Amount: Integer;
  CurrentStringIndex: Integer;
  LineIndex: Integer;
  Index: Integer;
  Delta: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Amount := 6;
  OutputFileName := 'С:\FileName_';
  FileExt := '.txt';

  SourceFile := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SourceFile.LoadFromFile('С:\FileToRead.txt');

    OutputFile := TStringlist.Create;
    try
      Delta := SourceFile.Count div Amount;
      CurrentStringIndex := 0;
      LineIndex := 0;
      Index := 0;

      for i:=0 to Delta - 1 do
        begin
          LineIndex := 0;
          while LineIndex <> Amount do
            begin
              OutputFile.Add(SourceFile.Strings[CurrentStringIndex]);
              Inc(CurrentStringIndex);
              Inc(LineIndex);
            end;

          OutputFile.SaveToFile(OutputFileName + IntToStr(Index) + FileExt);
          OutputFile.Clear;

          Inc(Index);
        end;

      // Осталось количество строк < Amount
      if CurrentStringIndex <> SourceFile.Count - 1 then
        begin
          // Загружаем предыдущий файл и добавляем к нему оставшиеся строки
          OutputFile.LoadFromFile(OutputFileName + IntToStr(Index - 1) + FileExt);
          while CurrentStringIndex <> SourceFile.Count do
            begin
              OutputFile.Add(SourceFile.Strings[CurrentStringIndex]);
              Inc(CurrentStringIndex);
            end;

          // Сохраняем получившийся файл
          OutputFile.SaveToFile(OutputFileName + IntToStr(Index - 1) + FileExt);
        end;
    finally
      OutputFile.Free;
    end;
  finally
    SourceFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

### Вариант чтения построчно

```
procedure TForm1.aButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileToRead: TextFile;
  OutputFile: TextFile;
  ReadString: String;
  OutputFileName: String;
  FileExt: String;
  Amount: Integer;
  CurrentStringIndex: Integer;
  LineIndex: Integer;
  Index: Integer;
  StringsAmount: Integer;
  NeedToAppend: Boolean;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Amount := 6;
  OutputFileName := 'С:\Output\FileName_';
  FileExt := '.txt';

  // Открываем файл для чтения
  StringsAmount := 0;
  AssignFile(FileToRead, 'С:\FileToRead.txt');
  try
    Reset(FileToRead);
    while not EoF(FileToRead) do
      begin
        ReadLn(FileToRead, ReadString);
        Inc(StringsAmount);
      end;
  finally
    // Закрываем файл
    CloseFile(FileToRead);
  end;

  // Открываем файл для чтения
  AssignFile(FileToRead, 'С:\FileToRead.txt');
  try
    Reset(FileToRead);

    CurrentStringIndex := 0;
    LineIndex := 0;
    Index := 0;

    // Работаем со строками в файле, открытом для чтения
    while not EoF(FileToRead) do
      begin
        // Проверяем превышение текущего показателя счетчика общего количества
        // прочитанных строк, и количества строк, которые должны содержаться
        // в файле (переменная Amount).
        if CurrentStringIndex + Amount <= StringsAmount + 1 then
          begin
            // Прочитано ли уже количество строк, указанное в переменной Amount?
            if LineIndex <> Amount then
              begin
                // Проверяем, нужно ли перезаписывать файл, т.е. создавать новый файл
                NeedToAppend := FileExists(OutputFileName + IntToStr(Index) + FileExt);

                // Загружаем/Создаем выходной файл и сразу же записываем в него строку
                AssignFile(OutputFile, OutputFileName + IntToStr(Index) + FileExt);
                try
                  if NeedToAppend then
                    Append(OutputFile)
                  else
                    Rewrite(OutputFile);

                  // Читаем строку из исходного файла
                  ReadLn(FileToRead, ReadString);

                  // Добавляем строку в выходной файл
                  WriteLn(OutputFile, ReadString);
                  Flush(OutputFile);

                  // Увеличиваем счетчики
                  Inc(CurrentStringIndex);
                  Inc(LineIndex);
                finally
                  // Закрываем файл
                  CloseFile(OutputFile);
                end;
              end
            else
              begin
                // Прочитали нужное количество строк - обновим индекс
                // следующего файла и сбросим счетчик.
                LineIndex := 0;
                Inc(Index);
              end;
          end
        else
          begin
            // В этой секции мы уже понимаем, что общее количество уже прочитанных
            // строк + количество строк, подлежащих прочтению, превышает общее
            // количество строк в файле. Поэтому необходимо загрузить последний
            // сохраненный файл и добавить в него оставшиеся строки.
            // Переменая Index осталась неизменной с момента последнего ее изменения.
            AssignFile(OutputFile, OutputFileName + IntToStr(Index) + FileExt);
            try
              Append(OutputFile);

              // Читаем строку из исходного файла
              ReadLn(FileToRead, ReadString);

              // Добавляем строку в выходной файл
              WriteLn(OutputFile, ReadString);
              Flush(OutputFile);

              // Увеличиваем счетчик
              Inc(CurrentStringIndex);
            finally
              // Закрываем файл
              CloseFile(OutputFile);
            end;
          end;
        end;
  finally
    // Закрываем файл
    CloseFile(FileToRead);
  end;
end;
```

Количество строк, которые надлежит поместить в файлы, зависит от значения переменной `Amount` (для примера (и теста) я поставил значение 6).

### Общий принцип работы

*Для первого варианта с целым файлом*

Высчитываем количество равных частей, которые должны содержаться в файлах. Затем создаем цикл и проходимся по оригинальному файлу, копируя равные части в файл для вывода. После достижения счетчиком цикла заданной отметки (переменная `Amount`) -  сохраняем файл.
В случае, если количество строк не делится нацело, необходимо добавить последние строки в новый файл. Для этого загружается заново последний сохраненный файл и к нему добавляются строки, после чего файл сохраняется.

*Для второго варианта - построчного чтения*

Читаем строку из файла и увеличиваем переменную `CurrentStringIndex`, отвечающую за количество прочитанных строк. После достижения этой переменной значения, эквивалентного значению переменной `Amount`, необходимо сохранить прочитанные строки в файл.

Если количество строк в файле не делится без остатка (т.е. файл еще не прочитан до конца, но известно, что количество оставшихся для чтения строк меньше необходимого уровня для создания нового файла), то для сохранения оставшихся строк исходного файла можно поступить следующим образом:

- Открыть предыдущий сохраненный файл.
- Прочитать строку из исходного файла и добавить ее в открытый предыдущий файл.
- Сохранить результат в текущий файл, так как он является последним файлом в очереди.

*Примечание*
Код для чтения построчно может выглядеть несколько нелепо. Особенно огорчает создание файла всякий раз, когда условие `LineIndex <> Amount` истинно. Тем не менее, благодаря этому получилось избежать применения `TStringList`.

Comment: @Денис, это происходит потому, что в конце каждой строки находятся символы CRLF - символы перехода на новую строку. Последняя строка (как и предыдущие) имеет эти визуально невидимые символы, из-за чего и появляется новая "пустая" строка. Эти символы можно убрать, но это уже за рамками Вашего текущего вопроса. В программе Notepad++ при включенной опции "Отображать все символы" Вы сможете увидеть эти самые символы перехода на новую строку.

Comment: Дмитрий а как будет выглядеть код чтением построчно. Только что проверил на файле в 100 мегабайт и программа выдала ошибку при которой сказано что не достаточно памяти. У меня 1 гигабайт оперативной памяти на компьютере. Потому построчно было бы в самый раз.

Comment: @Денис, построчно можно. Код для чтения файла построчно у Вас [уже есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/902113/223235). Адаптировать текущий код к чтению построчно вполне возможно. Но есть один нюанс: в вопросе нет *ни слова о построчном чтении*. На ruSO существует правило: один вопрос - один ответ. Кроме того, 100 МБ не слишком критический объем файла для чтения через `TStringList` даже с 1 ГБ оперативной памяти. Да и что у Вас за *150 строк* суммарным размером 100 МБ?

Comment: 3000 строк и размер 100 мегабайт. В вопросе добавил предпочтение - чтение построчно. Помогите допилить код чтением построчно. Дело в том, что моя оперативка, при загрузке в память - валится, комп старенький. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: @Денис, добавил вариант с построчным чтением, но на будущее - либо сразу излагайте все условия задачи, либо задавайте разные вопросы (отдельные).

Comment: Дмитрий. Огромнейший Respect. Этот вариант для моего старенького компа просто блеск. Все заработало Отлично

Answer (score 2):

Цикл `j:=0 to 15` делает 16 итераций,а не 15.

После цикла по `j`,видимо, нужно записать текущее содержимое `Arr` в файл.

А чтобы сформировать имя файла, можно использовать номер `(i-1) div 15`

Comment: MBo, Ну я так понял нужно:  sl.SaveToFile('Fayl.txt'); Но тогда создастся только один файл?

Comment: Последнее предложение я ведь не просто так написал. Добавьте номер к заготовке имени (например, с помощью format)

Comment: Посмотрите в теме - обновил код, но за моих кривых рук не работает. Где ошибка ?

Comment: 4 подстановочных параметра Format, но только один реальный аргумент. Уберите все %s, оставьте только %d. Про лишнюю итерацию не забудьте

Comment: Сделал и изменил код, посмотрите, но теперь просто создается один файл, то есть копируется оригинал и все.... Где то снова косяк, я допустил.

Comment: Ну почему sl - то?

Comment: Изменил и добавил код. Теперь создается только один файл на 15 строчек и все. Где еще косяк я допустил ?

Comment: Вы что, на автопилоте пишете код? Диагностика проблем по их проявлению - важный навык. Запись внутри цикла while должна быть.

Comment: Уже понял свой косяк. Я просто не в цикле обработку делал и потому один файл создавался.